# Error while reading an XML file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, vb.net

I need to read an XML file , but it skips some elements like "link" in this case , i put a breakpoint and i found that IsStartElement is false while the element is link .
any ideas ?

```
Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(New StringReader(Xml), settings)

While reader.Read()
    If reader.IsStartElement Then
        Select Case reader.Name
            Case "title"
                title = reader.ReadElementContentAsString()
            Case "link"
                link= reader.ReadElementContentAsString()
        End Select
    End If
End While
```

XML file

```
<title> title   1 </title>
<link>link 1 </link>
```

Comment: Is that the complete XML file, or just a fragment from it?

Comment: just a fragment , i want to add if i commented out { case "title" } i got the case "link" but i don't have a both of them

Comment: Can you post a complete, sample XML document that fails?  I just tested it by creating a document with those two elements under a root element and the code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You don't read the end elements.

It should be something along the lines of  (pseudocode):

```
if not reader.IsEmptyElement
    reader.ReadStartElement()
    value = reader.ReadContentAsSomething()
    reader.ReadEndElement()
else 
    reader.Skip()
```

You're missing the `ReadEndElement` and the checks for `IsEmptyElement`.

Comment: i don't get it can you explain more.

Comment: The idea is to consume the entire element, so that the next time you read, you're positioned at the start of the next sibling (if one exists). Empty elements can break the flow if you don't check for them with `IsEmptyElement` and then `Skip` them. Also, watch out for whitespace elements - it's usually best to set `IgnoreWhitespace = True` in the settings.